# error starting service

Tags: services, openerp

I just installed openerp by following the guidelines available on google and youtube but when i try to start the service it gives me the following error, can you please suggest what is going wrong.

```
    > ubuntu@ip-172:~$ openerp-server 
2014-03-06 12:00:35,954 9197 INFO ?
    > openerp: OpenERP version 7.0-20140306-001044 2014-03-06 12:00:35,955
    > 9197 INFO ? openerp: addons paths:
    > /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons 2014-03-06 12:00:35,955
    > 9197 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost 2014-03-06
    > 12:00:35,955 9197 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432 2014-03-06
    > 12:00:35,955 9197 INFO ? openerp: database user: ubuntu 2014-03-06
    > 12:00:36,441 9197 INFO ? openerp.addons.google_docs.google_docs: GData
    > lib version `%s GData-Python/2.0.14` detected Exception in thread
    > Thread-1: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
    > "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    >     self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
    >     self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line
    > 436, in serve
    >     httpd = werkzeug.serving.make_server(interface, port, application, threaded=True)   File
    > "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 399, in
    > make_server
    >     passthrough_errors, ssl_context)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 331, in
    > __init__
    >     HTTPServer.__init__(self, (host, int(port)), handler)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 408, in __init__
    >     self.server_bind()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
    >     SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 419, in server_bind
    >     self.socket.bind(self.server_address)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    >     return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args) error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
    > 
    > 2014-03-06 12:00:36,810 9197 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP server is
    > running, waiting for connections...
```

at the end line it says waiting for connections but it doesn't give me the prompt, I have to use crt+c/z

Answer (score 0):

It will not give you a prompt because its waiting a client to connect to it , this message means that your installation is correct .

This link will help you [Link](https://doc.openerp.com/6.0/book/1/1_1_Inst_Config/1_1_Inst_Config_install/)

Comment: why are these errors there for?

Comment: reboot and try again